# Android Drive API Read and write File

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I created an android app and i need to read a file from Drive and if needed to  overwrite the file.

I tried initially to use file.open with parameter read_only and then to write_only the file but the second call of file.open with parameter write_only is not fired (it seems to be ignored).

Then i tried to use the file.open with read_write parameter and i could read the file but i could not overwrite the file but only to append.

Have you experienced the same or something similar?

Comment: `Android Drive API` ? What is Android Drive API?

Comment: I mean Google Drive sdk and i use an old version ->10.2.6

Comment: i returned to the first attempt/solution by using once open_file with read_only parameter and then open_file with read_only parameter but changed the call to await and not to setResultCallback. It seems that there is a problem with calling twice the file.open for the same file